# Undefined error while executing octave program

Tags: octave

While executing the plotdata file in octave I'm getting the following error:

> plotData
>   error: 'x' undefined near line 7 column 6
>   error: called from
>       plotData at line 7 column 1
>    plotData
>   error: 'y' undefined near line 7 column 6
>   error: called from
>       plotData at line 7 column 1

My code:

```
function plotData(x, y)

figure;

plot(x,y,'rx','MarkerSize',10);

ylabel('Profit in $10,000s');

xlabel('Population of city in 10,000s');

end
```

Comment: Please add a complete piece oft code. See MCVE. Your call to plotData misses x and y

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Octave GNU: Undefined variable 'x' , even though it's defined as function input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508581/octave-gnu-undefined-variable-x-even-though-its-defined-as-function-input)

Answer (score 0):

plotData expects a x and y value to be provided when running.

if you press the run button on the GUI you aren't giving it an e, y value.

Likewise if you run as 'plotData' in the console window, you aren't giving an x,y value

In both cases, no x,y value means that x and y variables have not been defined in the function and so the error occurs.

If you ran as:

```
plotData(10,20)
```

You would not have the error occur as a x,y value is being provided.